# Transposing a numpy matrix causes cv's draw functions to throw errors

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I've been running into a few problems using cv to display images from numpy matrices when I transpose them.

Consider the following code.

```
import cv2, numpy as np
...
ones = np.ones((100,100))
onesT = np.copy(ones.T)
onesCT = np.copy(ones.T, order='C')
cv2.circle(ones, (50,50), 3, (0), thickness=-1)
cv2.circle(onesCT, (50,50), 3, (0), thickness=-1)
cv2.circle(onesT, (50,50), 3, (0), thickness=-1)
```

The first two "cv2.circle" calls work but the third one gives me the following error:

```
    102         cv2.circle(ones, (50,50), 3, (0), thickness=-1)
    103         cv2.circle(onesCT, (50,50), 3, (0), thickness=-1)
--> 104         cv2.circle(onesT, (50,50), 3, (0), thickness=-1)

TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

Why does this happen with transposed matrices but not if I change the order in which the memory is copied? To me, all those matrices are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one level of abstraction, all those matrices are the same.  But at a lower level, two of them have their data stored using the C convention ([row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)) for arrays, and the other (`onesT`) uses the Fortran convention (column-major order).  Apparently `cv2.circle` expects a C-contiguous array.

You can check the order using the `flags` attribute.  Note that the `F_CONTIGUOUS` flag of `onesT` is True:

```
In [24]: ones.flags
Out[24]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [25]: onesT.flags
Out[25]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [26]: onesCT.flags
Out[26]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

A concise way to check the order information is [`np.isfortran`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfortran.html):

```
In [27]: np.isfortran(onesT)
Out[27]: True
```

`onesT` uses the Fortran order because the transpose of a 2-d array is implemented in numpy by simply swapping the "strides" for each dimension, without actually copying the array of values in memory.

For example,

```
In [28]: x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

In [29]: np.isfortran(x)
Out[29]: False

In [30]: np.isfortran(x.T)
Out[30]: True
```

(This makes the transpose operation very efficient.)

You copied the transposed array to create `onesT`, but if you look at the docstring of [`np.copy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html), you'll see that the default value of the `order` argument is `'K'`, which means "match the layout of a as closely as possible."  In particular, it preserves the Fortran order in this case.  `onesCT`, on the other hand, is a C-contiguous array because you explicitly told `np.copy` to order the copy using the C convention.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough explanation!